# How can I schedule a Python script to upload files to One drive?

Tags: python, heroku, onedrive

I have a Python script that downloads some excel spreadsheets from a website, and then uploads these spreadsheets to a folder on OneDrive, at the moment I have to run this script on my machine every day, I would like to know if there is a way to run this script on a server or something, so I don't have to keep my computer on all the time.

I thought about uploading the script to Heroku and using the platform's scheduling service, but I don't know how to integrate with OneDrive

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  It would be helpful if you could provide the code in question.  You might also want to give more information as to how you're integrating with OneDrive now, and why you think that same approach won't work on Heroku.

Comment: You will use the Microsoft Graph REST API. There are various Python libraries that makes it easier to work with, such as https://github.com/GearPlug/microsoftgraph-python

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to schedule a python script to run without using your local machine. There are a few options for doing this:

Use a cloud-based computing service, such as Amazon Web Services (AWS) or Google Cloud Platform (GCP). These services allow you to set up virtual machines and run your python scripts on them.

Use a scheduling service, such as Cron or Windows Task Scheduler. These services allow you to set up a schedule for your python script to run at specific intervals.

Use a remote server or virtual private server (VPS). These allow you to access a machine remotely and run your python scripts on it.